# Sharepoint 2010 get position of ListItem

Tags: 2010, list, javascript

I'm working on a custom HTML Form in Sharepoint 2010 and for that I want to read the structure of a list with JavaScript, which contains items and folders.

What I did was loading all the Items ignoring the folder structure and then trying to get the parent folders from the items. The problem I run into is that I don't see any method that gives me all the parent folders or just an absolute or relative path, from which I could extract the folder names. I also tried to get the file of the ListItem and get a path from there but when I try to load the file I get `Cannot invoke method or retrieve property from null object. Object returned by the following call stack is null. "File"`. So my question is: Is it possible to get the path or the parent folders of a ListItem and if so how?

Here is my code:

```
var clientContext;
function retrieveListItems() {

    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Skills');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View Scope="Recursive"><Query></Query></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(Id, DisplayName, HasUniqueRoleAssignments, FileSystemObjectType)');

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listEnum = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    var listItemInfo = '';
    while(listEnum.moveNext()) {
        var $current = listEnum.get_current();
        $current.refreshLoad();
        console.dir($current);
        listItemInfo += "\n" + $current.get_displayName();

        var $file = $current.get_file();

        $("#LOG").append("\nCurrent " + print_r($current));
        $("#LOG").append("\nCurrent Path " + print_r($current.get_path()));
        $("#LOG").append("\nCurrent Path ID " + print_r($current.get_path().get_identity()));
        $("#LOG").append("\nFile: " + print_r($file));  
        clientContext.load($current.get_file(), "File");
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {
            $("#LOG").append("\nLevel: " + $current.get_file().get_level());
        }, function(sender, args) {
            $("#LOG").append("\nFailed: " + args.get_message());
        });

    }

    $("#LOG").append(listItemInfo);
}
```

Also if my approach is totally wrong I would appreciate a way to iterate through the List folder structure from the root folder.

Thanks in Advance

Patrick

Comment: Is that a list or library? For a list item it will be attachments. You question seems confusing!

Comment: @AtishDipongkor It's a list. So you mean the get_file() will get you the file attached to the ListItem not a file that IS the ListItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey so I figured out how to do it with the help of the example from @AtishDipongkor, though his example goes in another direction, it brought me on the right track.
I didn't know that you could use basic AJAX requests to get the data and it makes it a lot easier.
What I did, was to use the directions from Atish to get the right URL and then make a simple GET Request to that URL (I added accept: application/json to the header so that I get JSON instead of an ATOM XML Feed). The data I get from that contains all the Items with their Id, Title and absolute path w/o the domain name, so I just can search and replace.

```
$.ajax(siteUrl + "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Skills", {
    headers: {"accept": "application/json"},
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data.d.results, function(i, skill) {
            addSkill(skill);
        });
        loadedAllItems();
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, msg) {
        $("#LOG").append("\nErro: " + msg);
    },
});

function addSkill(data) {
    if(data["ContentType"] != "Item") {
        return;
    }

    var $path = data.Path;
    $path = $path.replace(siteUrl + "/Lists/Skills/", "");
    $folders = $path.split("/");
    var $level = allSkills;
    $.each($folders, function(i, $folder) {
        if(!$level.hasOwnProperty($folder)) {
            $level[$folder] = {};
        }
        $level = $level[$folder];
    });

    $level[data.Title] = data;
    $("#LOG").append("\n" + $path + "/" + data.Title);
}
```

Comment: You got the solution from my example but your answer is accepted! How come??

Comment: Because this is about finding a solution to the problem I asked about. And while your response was tremendously helpful, I documented how I solved the problem, thus making this the "right answer". I would have liked to select both as the accepted answer, since yours contains a core component of the solution, but it is unfortunately not possible.

Comment: You could update your question how you have solved rather than answering own question!

Comment: You're not supposed to do that

Answer (score 0):

Get the file path of a list item: Make an ajax request in following end-point.

```
http:/yoursiteurl/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/InductionAcknowledgement(1)/Attachments
```

Replace `InductionAcknowledgement` with your list name. Put item id inside first bracket `()`. Then you will get following response

```
{
  "__metadata": {
    "uri": "https://yourSiteUrl/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Attachments(EntitySet='InductionAcknowledgement',ItemId=1,Name='ACM%20Problem.docx')",
    "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.AttachmentsItem",
    "edit_media": "https://yourSiteUrl/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Attachments(EntitySet='InductionAcknowledgement',ItemId=1,Name='ACM%20Problem.docx')/$value",
    "media_src": "https://yourSiteUrl/Lists/Induction Acknowledgement/Attachments/1/ACM Problem.docx",
    "content_type": "application/octetstream",
    "media_etag": "\"{7992A4BD-AA01-4C4C-8FE3-8511F7CCF249},1\""
  },
  "EntitySet": "InductionAcknowledgement",
  "ItemId": 1,
  "Name": "ACM Problem.docx"
}
```

`__metadata.media_src` is your file path and `Name` is the file name.

Comment: I think I didn't explain properly what I wanted. I have a List that contains folders, subfolders and List Items (no attachments). I want to figure out where inside the folder structure an Item is located. But your example was very helpful nevertheless. I thought you only could get data from Sharepoint with executeQueryAsync, but with just a simple ajay request it's so much easier and you don't have to deal with requesting properties of objects and everything.

Comment: I have asked for so many things in a single question. I have answer one!